# Angular + Bootstrap dropdown close only on click outside

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to create a `dropdown` that does not close when I click any of its content  inside the `dropdown-menu`.
I can almost reach what I want if I just add a `form` tag containing the `dropdown-menu`, but when I click literally right on the `img` the dropdown closes.

---

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown">
            ...
        </button>
        
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <button (click)="someFunction()"
                        <span>Button Name</span>
                        <img src="path/img.svg">
                    ...
                </button>

                <button (click)="someFunction()"
                        <span>Button Name</span>
                        <img src="path/img.svg">
                    ...
                </button>
                    ...
        </div>
</div>
```

---

I also tried to implement this approach from the Bootstrap site (literally copied and pasted the example) but had no success: [Auto close behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior)

Adding the `data-auto-close="false"` to the same element that has the `data-toggle` also closes the dropdown when I click a button.

If there's anything that can be done inside the typescript of the component to reach please let me know.

Comment: The click event is probably bubbling up. You can try something like `<div class="dropdown-menu" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">`

Comment: That worked just fine! Thank you!